# Fixed length Character value as primary keys - will Entity Framework have an issue with it?

Tags: entity-framework, primary-key

My question here is two fold and I am seeking recommendation for these:

1. We have a transaction table which requires storage of a unique two character code for each record. Based on customer input and history, this table size will not grow more than 10 records in the near future. Thus is it advisable to make the two character code as Primary key for this table? (user will enter the code and we need to validate for uniqueness)
2. We will be using Entity Framework 6.0 as the ORM. Will using character primary key instead of numeric affect it in anyways?

Comment: A two-character key is **just fine** - EF needs a primary key - it really doesn't care about what makes up that primary key, as long as it's there!

Comment: Now, if all other tables in the database use auto increment integers as primary keys, is it okay to have this one as two characters OR replace it with integers and create the two character as a field?

Comment: Two characters, fixed length - all is fine! Just use it! No worries.